# How to make sense of dense layer units as dimensionality of predicted data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am dealing with a dataset that contains a time series data of 2 features x,y coordinates. I am interesting in predicting the future x,y (as a tuple, if possible ) from previous coordinates. I am fairly new to deep learning and I am closely following this article on Kaggle

[Intro to Recurrent Neural Networks LSTM | GRU](https://www.kaggle.com/thebrownviking20/intro-to-recurrent-neural-networks-lstm-gru)

google search gave me the answer that `input_shape` in a LSTM layer expects a 3D tuple (`batch_size, time_steps, feature`). Based on this knowledge, I dived into 2D data (x,y) :

```
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60,len(train_set_scaled)):
   X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i,0:2])
   y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i,0:2])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
print X_train.shape
(6208,60,2)
```

Since, it was 3D tuple, I didn't reshape it and continued.

```
## model begins here 
regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])) 
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units=2)) ## i am predicting future x,y
```

My code works, I am slightly unsure about output. Is it really future x,y that I am predicting? because If I give `units=3`, I get 3D output and `units=1`, I get 1D output. What that really means? I guess I am  forcing  my network to converge to `n` outputs when I am giving `units=n`. Let me know if my question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, after defining the model type you need to use the `model.fit` method to fit it to the data.

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The size of the output is defined by the shape of `y_train` i.e. the size of the labels vector for training.

To predict y you should do something like

```
y_prob = model.predict(X_test)
```

Hope this answer your question